# CMAKE add_includes

Tags: cmake

I have a codebase which has number of folders and each folder having some .c and .h files and a CMakelists.txt.
In all the CMakeLists.txt only .c files are added but not the headers as seen below.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12 FATAL_ERROR)

add_includes(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
add_sources(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/demo.c)
add_sources(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/demo1.c)
add_sources(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/demo2.c)
add_sources(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/demo3.c)
add_sources(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/demo4.c)
. . .
```

Does this "add_includes" will automatically pull the header files corresponding to the folder being built?
Not seeing any man page for add_includes.
What is the purpose of "add_includes"?

Comment: `add_sources` and `add_includes` are **not standard** CMake commands, but **part of your project**. So we can only *guess* about intention of these commands.

Comment: Oh yes you are correct Tsyvarev. add_sources and add_includes are macros in our code base. By its naming I assumed they are some CMake standard command like add_subdirectory.

Thanks for your suggestion.
This can be marked as closed.

Comment: FYI, it is not necessary to add header files in add_executable() or similar.  It's only done so that header files are listed in the appropriate place in Visual Studio and other IDEs.